# AngularJS Push in Collection, Show from Collection, $watch changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use object ITEMS to hold data

```
$scope.items = [
    {value:'title1', text: 'head1',
    value:'title2', text: 'head2',
    value:'title3', text: 'head3' }
];
```

When I clicked 'Add option' button I need show 'value' and 'text' in HTML page:

```
$scope.items.push(
    {
        value: 'value1',
        text: 'text1'
    }
);
```

I can show object length, but I can't show added option.
And $watch ($watchCollection) doesn't work too.

In this example I don't get values from inputs.

[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhlWoQJC9BvcmNe3FTnv?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$scope.items` array is improperly declared.  You need braces around each separate item in the array, like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    {value:'title1', text: 'head1'},
    {value:'title2', text: 'head2'},
    {value:'title3', text: 'head3'}
];
```

Your directive is all kinds of messed up.  You don't even need to create a new directive if all you want to do is display the items in a list.  You can just do this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.text for item in items"></select>
```

Your textboxes are ok, except for the typo in the `ng-model="addoText"`.  Your labels below should be bound to the same variables as the textboxes.

```
key: {{addVal}} <br>and value: {{addText}}
```

That will update the labels as you type in the textboxes.  If you don't want to update the labels until you add a new item, then bind them to some new variables, like this:

```
key: {{newVal}} <br>and value: {{newText}}
```

Finally, your `add()` function should look like this:

```
$scope.add = function () {          
    $scope.items.push(
        {
            value: $scope.addVal,
            text: $scope.addText
        }
     );

    $scope.newVal = $scope.addVal;
    $scope.newText = $scope.addText;
};
```

This pushes the new item to the array, and sets the bindings on your labels to the new values.  You don't need to `$watch` anything.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlZXjUFEfn3OY6iqVrdq?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with how your items array looks at the moment.
I think your $scope.items should look like:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        value: "value1",
        text: "text1"
    },
    {
        value: "value2",
        text: "text2"
    }
]
```

rather than all in one object, as when you push you'll create a new object.

With your question, calling items.value, will result in an undefined.

You need to call an object in $scope.items. Calling items[$scope.items.length-1] will get the most recent object added, and such items[$scope.items.length-1].value and items[$scope.items.length-1].text the values in that object